# Feynman’s integration technique.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Recently I've found an article about the Feynman's integration technique. A technique for solving hard integral, that the usual methods do not aply, or the usual methods would take realy long to solve, but the article, despite beeing very concise about the technique itself, jumps on a few steps that are told to be elementary, such as the partial fraction decomposition of a intemediate integral.

Well, I've tried to do the partial fraction but every try I do, I get something worse than presented, I dont know if I'm doing something wrong, but, if possible, I would like a detailed resolution of the integral down below.
To help I'm leting the site link [Richard Feynman’s integral trick](https://medium.com/@jackebersole/richard-feynmans-integral-trick-e7afae85e25c)

The integral mentioned above is:
$$I(x) = \int_0^1{\frac{ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} dx}$$
The problem treats it as a function of $\alpha$:
$$f(\alpha) = \int_0^1{\frac{ln(\alpha x+1)}{x^2+1} dx}$$
and states that $f(1) = I(x)$, and, $f(0) = 0$

As suggested my problem is in this steps.
$$1^{st}: \frac{\partial f(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{1}{{\alpha}^2+1}\int_0^1{\left(\frac{\alpha + x}{x^2+1} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha x+1} \right)d\alpha}$$
And the $2^{nd}$ is when it calls:
$$I(1) = \int_0^1{\frac{ln(\alpha+1)}{{\alpha}^2+1}d\alpha}$$

Thakfully,
liuzp

Comment: I suggest being more specific about what step exactly you've having difficulty with you. Even the abridged solution in the article is relatively long, and explaining all of the omitted details is a time-consuming and redundant undertaking, if you're only missing a few of them.

Comment: After the diferentiation, the article splits the integral in the partial fraction form, this is the first time that I could not understand.
The second time is by the end when the article calls an similar integral of $I(1)$ and passes to the other side of equality.

Comment: Can I revive some old post?
I think that I could solve my problem with a simple reply on the post of the $1^{st}$ coment, but, I'm afraid of digging down an old dead post.

Comment: Yes. I was trying by the method of assigning values to x such that all but one coefficiente becomes 0, however I keep getting strange thins for A, B and C.